# The NANNP Grid ( Not another Next Number Puzzle )

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence, algorithm, algebra

> **Simply figure out the last row...**

[image: Find next number in sequence]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So stacking

> Down from the first column is $11x + 16$. Then 6 x 11 = 66 + 16 = 82; 82 x 11 = 902 + 16 = 918. Then 918 x 11 = 10,098 + 16 = 10,114.

Then the rest

> Of the columns is found by multiplying by 3, then adding 4, then multiplying by 4.

So

> 10,114 x 3 = 30,342; 30,342 + 4 = 30,346; 30,346 x 4 = 121,384.

So the four numbers are

> 10,114; 30,342; 30,346; 121,384.

Comment: Very impressive. You guys never cease to amaze me how fast you are. I really need to step up the difficulty. Great Job @El-Guest